# Why is array_merge_recursive() not returning required output PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following string that I am trying to combine the inner array stop recursively and print the result as json data but seems like the `array_merge_recursive()` function is not producing the desired output.

The result I am getting whenever I run the code is the same. Am I missing something or is there an alternative function to achieve combining the inner array?

```
$routes = '[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "City Centre (Pangani)"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Muthaiga"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Utalii"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "KCA"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Drive Inn"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "Allsops"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "name": "GSU"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "Roasters"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "Ngumba"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "City Centre (Pangani)"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Muthaiga"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Utalii"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "KCA"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Drive Inn"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "Allsops"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "name": "GSU"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "Roasters"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "Ngumba"
            }
        ]
    }
]';
```

This is the desired output

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CBD - Ngumba via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "City Centre (Pangani)"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Muthaiga"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Utalii"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "KCA"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Drive Inn"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "Allsops"
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "name": "GSU"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "Roasters"
            },
            {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "Ngumba"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Ngumba - City Centre via Thika Road",
        "stop": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "City Centre (Pangani)"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Muthaiga"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Utalii"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "KCA"
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Drive Inn"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "Allsops"
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "name": "GSU"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "Roasters"
            },
            {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "Ngumba"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is what I have tried but still returns the data as is in the original string.

```
$routes = json_decode($routes);
echo json_encode(array_merge_recursive($routes));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because that's not how the function works. You need to write a custom function to achieve desired result.

```
function merge_result($data) 
{
   $result = [];
   $index = 0;
   $keys = [];
   foreach($data as $row) 
   {
       if(array_key_exists($row['id'], $keys)){
           $_index = $keys[$row['id']];
           $result[$_index]['stop'] = array_merge($result[$_index]['stop'], $row['stop']);
       }else {
           $keys[$row['id']] = $index; 
           $result[$index] = $row; 
          $index++;
       }

   }
  return $result;
}

$routes = merge_result(json_decode($data, true));
```

<sup>*PS: Am unable to test because am on mobile phone.*</sup>

Comment: After correcting some typos your solution throws the following error:  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in....` for this line `foreach($data as $row1)`

Comment: Use `json_decode($data,  true)` to return associative array